# Is it bad practice to use an object property instead of the object as a dependecy in the useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I use the following code in my functional component. I want this component only to re-render when `game._id` changes. But React keeps giving me the warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'game'. Either include
> it or remove the dependency array

Is this a dangerous practise or is it justified if I explicitly want it to depend on the given property?

```
  const [game, setGame] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (game._id !== undefined) {
       // Do stuff with game
      }
    };
  }, [socket, user, game._id]);
```

I do not want to use game as a dependency, because that makes my component re-render way to much.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Answer (score 4):

The dependency array checks if a value changed since the last render. It doesn't care where the value came from, or what it's shape. The problem is with the linter, that sees the use of `game` inside `useEffect`, although it's not registered as a dependency. Declare `gameId` and assign it the value of `game._id`, and use it as a dependency, and inside `useEffect`:

```
const [game, setGame] = useState({});

const gameId = game._id;

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // use gameId inside useEffect
    if (gameId !== undefined) {
      // Do stuff with game
    }
  };
}, [socket, user, gameId]); // set gameId as dependency
```

Comment: This solution could help in the case when I only used the `game._id`, but I actually use the `game` object in that if statement (I should have made that more clear). So the linter still wants to see game as a dependency.

Comment: So it that case, `game` is a dependency, and you need to include it.